# RE: Autocomplete in IE & Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, autocomplete

How can I completely destroy, kill, and permanently erase the 'Autocomplete' function in such a way that I never have to deal with it again?

Answer (score 0):

## Firefox

Here are the steps to disable Auto Form Fill according to this [Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-firefox-automatically-fills-in-forms?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Form+autocomplete):

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button and then select Options.
2. Select the Privacy panel
3. Set *Firefox will:* to *Use custom settings for history*
4. Remove the check mark from the box that says *Remember search and form history*
5. Click OK to close the Options window .

**Note:** Disabling form history also prevents Firefox from storing search history for the Search bar in the Navigation Toolbar.

To clear your Auto Fill history, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and select *Everything* and make sure to only check *Form & Search history* down below. Click *Clear Now* to erase your history.

To disable [inline autocomplete](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Inline_autocomplete) in your location bar

1. Type `about:config` in the Location Bar
2. Right-click on the page and create a new boolean value
3. Type `browser.urlbar.autoFill`
4. Set the value to `false`

In case you'd rather configure *inline autocomplete* in your location bar than disable it, have a look at the `browser.urlbar.default.behavior`<sup>1</sup> and `browser.urlbar.autoFill.typed`<sup>2</sup> preferences.

If you also want to disable the drop-down menu in your location bar, add a new boolean value called `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled` and set the value to `false`.

## Internet Explorer

1. Open Tools → Internet Options
2. Select the Content tab from the top of the dialog box
3. Click on Settings in the AutoComplete section of the window
4. In the AutoComplete Settings box, uncheck the appropriate boxes
5. *[optional]* Press *Delete AutoComplete history...* to delete your AutoComplete history
6. Click OK

---

<sup>1</sup> Possible values according to [Mozilla's Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.default.behavior):

```
  1 Restrict: History
  2 Restrict: Bookmarks
  4 Restrict: Tags
  8 Match: Title
 16 Match: URL
 32 Restrict: Typed
 64 Restrict: JavaScript
128 Restrict: Open Tabs (Switch to tab)
```

Simply add up the digits to combine filters, e. g. 3 means restrict to visited bookmarks.

<sup>2</sup> When `browser.urlbar.autoFill.typed` is set to `true` it means that only addresses you've manually typed into the urlbar get autofilled. When the preference is set to `false` then all addresses stored in your history are eligible for autofill.